# Database Cleanup after every junit test cases with http calls

Tags: spring, rest, java-8, junit4, hsqldb

I am using junit4 with spring to test my rest web services. 
For this, I am using HSQL in memory database.

To clean the records after every test case, I am removing all the records from tables.

But I want to delete only inserted records.
I am adding data to database in two places:

1. In Junit test cases.
2. In the rest services.

I am making **http calls** to test the services. Also, I am using same  in-memory database in rest services.

Kindly help me in removing only inserted records after each test cases.

**Edited**: My concern is deleting the inserted records in http calls to rest services. It is really hard to keep track of those records. They are part of my actual code.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `@Before` and `@After` methods to perform this activity.

Note that `@Before` will be executed before every test and `@After` will be executed after every Test .So `@Before` you should insert the records , now you know which records have been inserted , delete only them in `@After`

If you want to add few different records for each test then use try ....  finally

like below

```
class Test{
     @Before
        public void setUp(){
             // insert x Records 
        }


      @After
        public void tearDown(){
             // delete x Records 
        }


         @Test
                public void someTest() throws Exception {
              //  ... insert few records 
                try{
                doSomething();
              }finally{
            //  deleteRecordsInserted for this test.
             }

            }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I thought of this. My concern is deleting the inserted records in http calls to rest services. It is really hard to keep track of those records. They are part of my actual code.