# How to dispose bean resources in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dispose

I have some disposable resources inside a bean. I was not noticing it until tried to use `@DirtiesContext` in testing. With this annotation, spring drops context after test and then initializes it again, which caused an error for me. Thus I found that resources are not disposed.

So. How to dispose resources gracefully?

Comment: In testing you probably make an `@After` method and clean it up yourself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234936/database-cleanup-after-every-junit-test-cases-with-http-calls .

Comment: Is it possible to implement with test-agnostic manner?

Comment: I guess that depends on what kind of resource you want to dispose.

Comment: Possibly via @PreDestory in the bean: http://www.journaldev.com/2637/spring-bean-life-cycle-methods-initializingbean-disposablebean-postconstruct-predestroy-aware-interfaces